What is wrong with my function overload with 8 different argument combinations?
I am trying to override Pydantic's and SQLModel's Field function.
I have 3 boolean arguments which indicate different combinations:

If is_table_field == True, then return SQLModel's FieldInfo, else return Pydantic's FieldInfo
If is_state_field == True, then the additional_state_description argument must be specified. If it is False then it must not be specified
If is_tag_field == True, then the additional_tag_description argument must be specified. If it is False then it must not be specified

Here is my code:
from typing import Literal, overload

from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo as PydanticFieldInfo
from sqlmodel.main import FieldInfo as SQLModelFieldInfo


# TTT
@overload
def Field(
    description: str,
    is_table_field: Literal[True],
    is_state_field: Literal[True],
    is_tag_field: Literal[True],
    additional_state_description: str,
    additional_tag_description: str,
) -> SQLModelFieldInfo:
    ...


# TTF
@overload
def Field(
    description: str, is_table_field: Literal[True], is_state_field: Literal[True], additional_state_description: str
) -> SQLModelFieldInfo:
    ...


# TFT
@overload
def Field(
    description: str, is_table_field: Literal[True], is_tag_field: Literal[True], additional_tag_description: str
) -> SQLModelFieldInfo:
    ...


# TFF
@overload
def Field(description: str, is_table_field: Literal[True]) -> SQLModelFieldInfo:
    ...


# FTT
@overload
def Field(
    description: str,
    is_state_field: Literal[True],
    is_tag_field: Literal[True],
    additional_state_description: str,
    additional_tag_description: str,
) -> PydanticFieldInfo:
    ...


# FTF
@overload
def Field(description: str, is_state_field: Literal[True], additional_state_description: str) -> PydanticFieldInfo:
    ...


# FFT
@overload
def Field(description: str, is_tag_field: Literal[True], additional_tag_description: str) -> PydanticFieldInfo:
    ...


# FFF
@overload
def Field(description: str) -> PydanticFieldInfo:
    ...


def Field(
    description: str,
    is_table_field: bool = False,
    is_state_field: bool = False,
    is_tag_field: bool = False,
    additional_state_description: str | None = None,
    additional_tag_description: str | None = None,
) -> PydanticFieldInfo | SQLModelFieldInfo:
    if is_table_field:
        # TODO: implement
        return SQLModelFieldInfo()

    # TODO: implement
    return PydanticFieldInfo()

But MyPy is giving me all of these errors:

Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2
Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 3
Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 5
Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 6
Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 7

What cases am I not covering?

Where is is_tag_field in the second @overload?

From what I understood, as it has a default value of False in the main implementation, it can be excluded from any overload where it's value is False. Is that not correct?

I would call the second overload like field = Field(description="a", is_table_field=True, is_state_field=True, additional_state_description="b") which doesn't give any erorrs in my IDE.

Why have the Boolean parameters at all? For instance, if additional_state_desription can be None if and only if is_state_field is True, why not just infer the value of is_state_field based on the value of additional_state_description?

Do you really need the flag is_state_field? Can't you test if additional_state_description has a value to get the same thing?
